# How can I put two inclined divs side by side using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two inclined divs side by side. I don't know if this is possible in CSS, but I want to do something like this:

[image: Example]

It's just an example.

I was thinking about using a gradient background, but it doesn't work, because I want to do a responsive layout with multiple backgrounds.

```
<style>
    body {
        background:
            linear-gradient(
                to top left,
                black,
                black 50%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,
                rgba(0,0,0,0)
            )
            top center no-repeat,

            linear-gradient(
                to top right,
                black,
                black 50%,
                #007bff 50%,
                #007bff
            )

            top center no-repeat;
            background-size:40% 200%;
            background-color: black;
            padding:0;
            margin:0 auto;
            min-height:100%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You want triangular divs? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: triangular divs is a good way to do it, i tried, but i was afraid because i couldnt use percentages, and i want to do a responsive layout.

Comment: tthe gradient background seems to be a good solution to draw the triangle, but does the question is that you are having troubles to fill your divs ?

Comment: im having troubles to put images inside the triangle

Comment: can you do a fiddle or codepen ? this kind ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zruqi ?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with ::before and ::after pseudo elements for divs?

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #bleft {
                border-bottom: 500px solid black;
                border-right: 500px solid transparent;
                float:left;
            }

            #bright {
                border-bottom: 500px solid black;
                border-left: 500px solid transparent;
                float:right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="bleft"></div>
        <div id="bright"></div>
    </body>

    <body>
        <div id="bleft"></div>
        <div id="bright"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: How is that responsive? This is what the OP said he had already but didn't want

Comment: The sample HTML is not well formed. E.g. double "body" tag.